# jQuery live() + focus() - ui autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Just need a little help with jquery - i'm trying to change search option "w" passed to php by json on a fly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
          $('.auto').live('keydown.autocomplete', function(){
             $('.auto').focus(function() {
                var col = $(".auto").closest("td").attr("col");
                var srs = "search_tip.php?w="+col;
            });

            $(this).autocomplete({
                source: srs,
                dataType: "json",
                minLength: 2
            });
          });
        });
    </script>
```

Basically depending on attribute "col" of parent  - script search searches different tables in database. here is HTML bit:

```
<tr primary_key="1">
<td col="catalogue" class="editableCell" style="width: 80px; "><input class="editableInput auto" type="text"></td>
<td col="artist" class="editableCell" style="width: 100px; "><input class="editableInput auto" type="text"></td>
<td col="title" class="editableCell" style="width: 206px; "><input class="editableInput auto" type="text"></td>
</tr>
```

Without `$('.auto').focus(function() {});` - js only picks up first instance (in this case "catalogue"), but i need it to pick up for each .auto instance, changing table name.
But with focus() - it doesn't work at all =)

let me know if this is clear enough, or you need more info

thanks!

Comment: Your 'srs' variable is not visible when you supply it to $(this).autocomplete; it is scoped at $('.auto').focus callback function. Perhaps this might help you?

Comment: yes, i sort off guessed that, but hoped that $('.auto').live() scope will do the trick. ok, what is the best way passing variable into $(this).autocomplete? - $(this).autocomplete(function(srs) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try the following:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('.auto').live('keydown.autocomplete', function(){
      var col = $(this).closest("td").attr("col");
      var srs = "search_tip.php?w=" + col;
      $(this).autocomplete({
          source: srs,
          dataType: "json",
          minLength: 2
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: thanks! this worked! all I need to do to my original code was to add  $(this).closest("td")! insane ! i was close =)

Answer (score 0):

Why not save the value in a hidden input then use it in the autocomplete.
Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
              $('.auto').live('keydown.autocomplete', function(){
                 $('.auto').focus(function() {
                    var col = $(".auto").closest("td").attr("col");
                    $('#hidden_col').val(col);
                });

                $(this).autocomplete({
                    source: "search_tip.php?w="+$('#hidden_col').val(),
                    dataType: "json",
                    minLength: 2
                });
              });
            });
        </script>
```

In the html add the hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidden_col" />
```

Comment: thanks, but i can't see the way as class ".auto" also is generated by the grid on the fly...